# LOo don't start : Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-gnome

> cylere@Lalla:~$ uname -a
>   Linux Lalla 3.19.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:17:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> cylere@Lalla:~$ cat /etc/issue
>   Ubuntu 15.10 \n \l

- The command line `soffice` or `loffice` lock with no return, necessary to use CTRL+C to exit.
- With icon *soffice* or *writer*, a popup with error :

> "Impossible to launch the application."
>   Failed to updatefile:///home/cylere/.config/libreoffice/4/user/extensions/bundled/lastsynchronized

This file (*lastsynchronized*) have only the character `1` inside.

- > Sometime on the terminal
  >   (soffice:3567): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

They are all messages I got, and ***LibreOffice don't start***.

---

This appear from some time, but I could use *soffice* or *loffice* to start LOo, but after a recent upgrade, nothing works

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 was released with kernel 4.2. How did you end up with 3.19?

Comment: @mikewhatever -- I let automatic upgrade do the job (from a French server) since I've installed Ubuntu !! How can I upgrade the system without breaking all things around ?

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps - I had the same issue (with the same warning) and solved it by deleting the folder .config/libreoffice. It got recreated when I launched libreoffice again. I'm sure I lost some settings but nothing important...

Comment: Efficient after migration to 20.04

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04. the same error keeps happening, even after deleting .config/libreoffice