# In 16.04, Libreoffice crashes my OS

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

Ever since I updated to 16.04, Libreoffice has been crashing my computer. In particular, if I try to go through with document recovering it will crash every time (and return to the login menu). The only option I can take is to click the x on the recover window, the option to recover or remove recovery data both cause a crash. Also, when I try to save a tiny spreadsheet as .csv it has been crashing.

Comment: Have you installed all the available software updates for your system?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Ya, I just did apt-get update/upgrade, and it is still doing it.

Comment: Instead of launching LibreOffice as you normally do, try opening a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and type `libreoffice`. Now when it crashes, there *should* be some info displayed in the terminal window that can help track down what might be going on.

Comment: @NickWeinberg, when it crashes it takes the OS with it, closing the terminal. I tried running it with `libreoffice >> log_file 2>&1`, but the only thing which shows up is: `(soffice:5839): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large`

`(soffice:5839): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large`
`X IO Error`

I know that these errors occur before I click the button to start recovery.

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/753020/loo-dont-start-gdk-warning-gdk-window-set-icon-list-icons-too-large (???) You could try editing `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/extensions/bundled/lastsynchronized`
and replace the 1 inside by a 0 (zero).

Comment: Nothing was written to the log this time, but still crashed.

Comment: Maybe disabling OpenGL may help. Check Menu Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> View. If you can't reach the options menu, you can [disable it manually, too](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/OpenGL#Crash_on_program_start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by installing the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package.
Seems to be a problem with the generic modesetting xorg driver in my case.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This was my problem too. Although not on Ubuntu and it happened only with password protected ods files. The xf86-video-modesetting driver was not good enough. Video card: GMA 4500MHD on GM45 chipset.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an OpenGL driver for your video card, that is probably the problem. For me, installing the video card driver for my card (an NVIDIA GeForce 9400M) was able to get LibreOffice working. If you can't install the driver, try disabling OpenGL in LibreOffice.