# Unity crashes when I open LibreOffice document

Tags: 16.04, unity, libreoffice

When I open a LibreOffice document, the window "quivers" (gets slightly smaller and and then bigger repeatedly, top menu columns (`file`, etc.) jump from the top menu to window menu and back) and Unity seems to crash (top menu columns and icons at the right disappear). I need to log out and back in or restart Unity to get the top menu back. If I open LibreOffice without a document, its alright until I open a document.

Syslog shows this, when it happens:

```
Jan 16 09:59:21 AP-X kernel: [  451.980357] unity-panel-ser[3132]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fc5be712425 sp 00007fff9885f548 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fc5be685000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:21 AP-X kernel: [  452.531584] unity-panel-ser[4654]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7e5a48c425 sp 00007ffc03ca0128 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f7e5a3ff000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:22 AP-X kernel: [  453.085363] unity-panel-ser[4676]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb1dde01425 sp 00007ffc1ed7d978 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fb1ddd74000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:22 AP-X kernel: [  453.675899] unity-panel-ser[4689]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f061acce425 sp 00007ffedc6e6d58 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f061ac41000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:23 AP-X kernel: [  454.338166] unity-panel-ser[4702]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa0c4a53425 sp 00007ffdd8657188 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fa0c49c6000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:23 AP-X kernel: [  454.772976] unity-panel-ser[4715]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f277ddd5425 sp 00007ffd8403ff28 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f277dd48000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:24 AP-X kernel: [  455.216108] unity-panel-ser[4727]: segfault at 0 ip 00007ff7dca61425 sp 00007ffda130ead8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ff7dc9d4000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:24 AP-X kernel: [  455.654618] unity-panel-ser[4739]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f9a7e444425 sp 00007ffdd0dfddd8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f9a7e3b7000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:25 AP-X kernel: [  456.078362] unity-panel-ser[4751]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f78dbfbd425 sp 00007ffcede472f8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f78dbf30000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:26 AP-X kernel: [  457.349191] show_signal_msg: 2 callbacks suppressed
Jan 16 09:59:26 AP-X kernel: [  457.349196] unity-panel-ser[4789]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fefcc629425 sp 00007ffc2c21e6e8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fefcc59c000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:26 AP-X kernel: [  457.741482] unity-panel-ser[4802]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa639ad9425 sp 00007ffd9b4fdd28 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fa639a4c000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:27 AP-X kernel: [  458.159408] unity-panel-ser[4814]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fd2bfdd5425 sp 00007ffcffb286b8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fd2bfd48000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:27 AP-X kernel: [  458.568686] unity-panel-ser[4827]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa17bb6c425 sp 00007ffc701a3a38 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fa17badf000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:28 AP-X kernel: [  458.988591] unity-panel-ser[4840]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fd4074b9425 sp 00007ffd97ec1928 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fd40742c000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:28 AP-X kernel: [  459.405718] unity-panel-ser[4853]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f3472a7e425 sp 00007ffd565cb398 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f34729f1000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:28 AP-X kernel: [  459.796760] unity-panel-ser[4865]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa14ed81425 sp 00007ffc758b07a8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fa14ecf4000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:29 AP-X kernel: [  460.203387] unity-panel-ser[4877]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fea84555425 sp 00007ffdca9dc9d8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fea844c8000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:29 AP-X kernel: [  460.609269] unity-panel-ser[4889]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fdff3bbc425 sp 00007ffdb8721428 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fdff3b2f000+1c0000]
Jan 16 09:59:30 AP-X kernel: [  461.020533] unity-panel-ser[4901]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f6cdd69c425 sp 00007ffc7b563c98 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f6cdd60f000+1c0000]
```

I am running LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

This issue is also filed at the [Ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1716295?comments=all) but has not been worked on since 09/2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2) on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (I haven't checked the Syslog though). I noticed that when opening libreoffice from terminal I had this output:

```
(soffice:2579): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
```

Looking that message up led me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753020/loo-dont-start-gdk-warning-gdk-window-set-icon-list-icons-too-large?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer, which probably is completely unrelated. But I decided to try the solution proposed just in case, and it seems to have fixed the problem. Proposed answer:

```
rm -r ~/.config/libreoffice
```

The folder will be created anew when libreoffice is launched again. I think the previous configuration should be lost, but this is probably affordable.

After doing this the output from terminal I get when running libreoffice is as follows:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx


(soffice:2568): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:2579): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:2579): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
```

Which is probably why I think the Gdk-WARNING is completely unrelated to the issue.